# Shipping Information Content

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout

I want to **include Company field** on the **shipping-information-content** block on the Checkout if a customer fills the field on the previous page.

The relevant block on **checkout_index_index.xml** is

```
<item name="shipping-information" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress</item>
    </item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shipping-information</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="ship-to" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information/list</item>
            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">ship-to</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

I added a picture that specifies which block I mean:

[image: Screenshot of missing shipping information]

Can anyone offer their advice?

Comment: can't see the image , upload again

Comment: Company field already exists in Magento2 on checkout page.

Comment: I added a direct link to imgur for the picture @Manoj

Comment: I know that it exists, I want it to show on the Ship To: section on the last page of our checkout!

Comment: okay got it , let me see if I can help you on this

Comment: Try the solution I posted and let me know if any problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Adding company field on the Ship To section and shipping address follow below steps :

To **add Company/New field** in **shipping address section**, override:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html
```

To add **Company/New field** field in  **sidebar Ship To section** override:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html
```

To override create `requirejs-config.js` at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html':
                'Vendor_Module/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html',

            'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html':
                'Vendor_Module/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html'
        }
    }
};
```

After that  add this line of code in overridden file where you want to **display company field**.

```
<!-- ko text: address().company --><!-- /ko -->
```

For example

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

```
<div class="shipping-address-item" data-bind="css: isSelected() ? 'selected-item' : 'not-selected-item'">
    <!-- ko text: address().prefix --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().firstname --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko text: address().lastname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().suffix --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().street --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().company -->
    <!-- ko text: address().city --><!-- /ko -->, <!-- ko text: address().region --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().postcode --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: getCountryName(address().countryId) --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().telephone --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element' } -->
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute' } -->
            <!-- ko text: element[attribute].value --><!-- /ko -->
         <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: (address().isEditable()) -->
    <button type="button"
            class="action edit-address-link"
            data-bind="click: editAddress, visible: address().isEditable()">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: selectAddress" class="action action-select-shipping-item">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Ship Here'"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Then run necessary commands , hope this should help you out.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work. The requirejs-config.js file breaks the part at the bottom right completely, it shows an error message specifying that the call to the correct files does not exist. Further I only have company showing at the bottom right, after which it shows completely nothing. However I overwrote the files not under app/code/... but under app/design/...

Comment: You responded late , left from work-station, will help you tomorrow to solve this

Comment: have you copied files from vendor to  app/code ?

Comment: But why to app/code? It is a layout change right, so should it not be copied to app/design? In app/code I only have plugins

Comment: not a layout , you are adding that in Ship TO Section, if already present there than you can move via XMl , so its better to extend as suggested and try, that will solve your problem

Comment: I now added the files to /app/code/Smartwave/Porto/view/frontend/web/template/ but it is now the same as before. The section at the bottom right now only shows data up until company and then doesnt show anything after that.

Comment: Cannot get it to work even though I seem to do it exactly as you said :/

Comment: yes try same as i mentioned , hope so works for you

Comment: Does this solution work? as I am also getting the broken requirejs-config file in the right down corner under 'ship to:' area

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html**

Add following code after country for displaying company (Right sidebar renderer)

```
<!-- ko text: address().company --><!-- /ko -->
```

For under payment method add following code after country:

**Overwrite [vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html]**

```
<!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().company --><!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: For some reasons this is not working for me: I edited the files in my theme and did the redeploy but the changes is not taking effect. I tried to change the magento core files and it worked, but if I change it on my custom theme it is not working. Any idea?